# Changing the vendor folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it right to change the vendor folder means the placement

my folder structure

```
theme
 --theme
    --files(app,bootstrap,config etc..)
 --vendor
    --vendor files
 --artisan
```

Is this right or not?

Comment: This is very subjective. I could think that vendor has not relation with a theme.  Or do you image a vendor folder per theme?

Comment: Theme folder means the basic laravel root files@manix

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve that structure?

Comment: Some kinda task from higher ! Is that wrong ?@manix

Comment: I'd call it "bad practices", because the vendor folder is used to store all dependencies integrated with your application. The vendor folder has not relations with themes, so you can have so much themes as needed using  the unique vendor folder normally.